# French Language in Android App

Tags: android

I developed an Android app it's working fine, but whenever the user login **in french language the Logout button is showing like D�connexion instead of Déconnexion.**

This app needs to support both English and French Languages, please help me how to solve this issue.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: how you have put your localization string in the string file?

Comment: did you follow this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: I copied Déconnexion into my app. and it worked fine.

Comment: I had that problem before on another app. I couldn't solve it. do you set that text on xml or in code?

Comment: I didn't add anything in my strings.xml file, all my data come from server to the app.

Comment: It is a simple character encoding problem. Make sure you use the same encoding on the server side and on the client side.

Comment: Hi Henry, I am using same encoding on both server and client ie UTF-8 and I have other app for j2me it's also connect same server, it is showing correct value.

Comment: did you try to set text manually in xml files? if it didnt work change default encoding until it work. then, you will know which encoding to use. it is definitely

Comment: Did you try to set text in xml??

Comment: Hi hasan, I tried with xml it's working fine. But I don't want to use xml file because all my data is coming from database, no need to write another xml file. is there any other way without using xml file?

Comment: I just wanted to check if it is working using xml. I know that you don't want to use it.

Comment: What is your eclipse default file encoding?

Comment: Hi hasan, it is taking Cp1252.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an app with files that include arabic text. When I copy that project to another computers. all letters become a trash. The solution was to change eclipse files default encoding:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding
```

Try:

```
UTF-8 and Latin-1
```

You mentioned that all your text come from the server. Try, to set encoding to those text to latin-1 after you receive it. worth a try. even if the server send it with UTF-8 encoding.

Set text manually in xml files. Change Eclipse default encoding until it work. then, you will know which encoding to use. it is definitely an encoding problems. as other also said.

Comment: Hi hasan, I have other apps which connect same server in those apps it's showing correct, in Android also the french language is shwoing but some symbols are displaying wrong format.

Comment: Hi hasan, thank you verymuch it's working fine. I changed this workspace encoding to UTF-8 then it's working fine, thank you.